# How to generate a title for the page?

Tags: bokeh

How can I output a title for a bokeh generated page similar to the functionality provided by [shiny's titlePanel](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/titlePanel.html)?

```
titlePanel(title, windowTitle = title)
```

Here is a shiny screenshot showing the title "Movie explorer":

[image]

I've seen this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877519/how-to-add-text-to-html-files-generated-by-python-bokeh) asking how to output generic text, but I'm specifically asking about generating a page title which I'm hoping there is a widget to help with that although I couldn't see anything in the bokeh [reference docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference.html).

Comment: Downvoters: please state why you are down voting so that I can improve my question.  Downvoting without a comment is a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: There is a `Div` widget that can be used to output HTML. See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py#L37

Comment: Thanks, Alexander.  If you want to add your comment as an answer, I will accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4741744/alexander-rodin) comment, there is a Div widget that can be used to output HTML. See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py.  I'm adding this as an answer so the question can be closed.